# Search text in page with JavaScript not working with IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code:

```
function doSearch(text) {
    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
        document.designMode = "on";
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

        while (window.find(text)) {
            document.getElementById("button").blur();
            document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "yellow");
            sel.collapseToEnd();
        }
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        while (textRange.findText(text)) {
            textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
            textRange.collapse(false);
        }
    }
}

<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" id="button" onmousedown="doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)" value="Find">
```

It's working on both Chrome and IE, but in IE, when you search something it's only highlighting the text I've searched but won't "jump" to where it is like Chrome do. It's a simple web page for employees of company have access to just a few lines of informations. And of course, some users don't know or just don't want to do a "CTRL + F" so I decided to make something like that.

Someone have some tip to make it work on IE? I need it to work with IE because almost all employees need to use it for your jobs.

Comment: These APIs may not be part of the standard. Have you looked up caniuse.com?

Comment: As I saw here, perhaps it is not supported with IE 11 more. Just older versions. Sad!